# How to use the dd command to copy the content of a folder

Tags: dd

I'm trying to use the `dd` command to copy the content of the folder boot0 to the my disks intial bytes.

This is the command :

```
sudo dd if=boot0/ of=/dev/sdb ibs=440 obs=440 count=1
```

But I get this error :

```
dd: error reading ‘boot0/’: Is a directory
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000209512 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `dd` reads files, not folders. As it is, that's not the proper way to write files to the start of a drive. You need to create a FAT32 partition first and then use `cp` to copy the contents over.

Comment: I think you want to use rsync, man rsync.

Answer (score 11):

## It can be done

**We need to workaround two problems:**

1. `dd` doesn't know what to do with directories
2. `dd` can only copy one file at a time

First let's define input and output directories:

```
SOURCE="/media/source-dir"
TARGET="/media/target-dir"
```

Now let's `cd` into the source directory so `find` will report relative directories we can easily manipulate:

```
cd "$SOURCE"
```

Duplicate the directory tree from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET`

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$TARGET{}" \;
```

Duplicate files from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET` omitting write cache (but utilising read cache!)

```
find . -type f -exec dd if={} of="$TARGET{}" bs=8M oflag=direct \;
```

Please note that this won't preserve file modification times, ownership and other attributes.

Comment: I get the dot in the of= dd parameter. How to get rid of it? I want to copy files from just one directory to another

Comment: `dd: {}: No such file or directory`

Comment: dd is used to copy even an entire disk. For dd all are BYTES and bits, that's why it copies even the MBR at offset 0-512 of the disk. The problem is that people want to guess WHERE their files are in a disk. For instance, Thunar said all files in my usb stick = 12MB but... when I scanned the 2GB image with python I discover that some files were at offset 100MB in the disk, so a dd stopped at 15MB would be corrupted.

Answer (score 8):

The main purpose of `dd` utility is to convert and copy files.

For example:

```
dd if=filename of=filename2 conv=ucase
dd if=/dev/urandom of=myrandom bs=100 count=1
```

If you'd like to copy the content of the folder use either `rsync`:

```
rsync -vuar src/ dst/
```

or `cp` utility:

```
cp -va src/. dst/
```

Comment: `-R` / `-r` not required when using `-a` as `-a` always implies recursive.

Comment: It is not an answer to the question, it its a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

> dd works on the file you specify, making it able to copy data between devices, or from a device to a file. This is commonly used for moving data if devices specifically are involved (create an iso image from a cd-rom disc for example: dd if=/dev/cdrom of=mycdrom.iso), or backup raw devices (sometimes used in RAC databases: dd if=/dev/raw/raw1 of=device_raw1)
>
> cp is used for duplicating file content to a new file or to a new location. things you specifically want there are preservation of ownership, timestamp and mode (rights), and being able to recurse the operation (=being able to copy directories).

Try this command :

```
   cp -r /home/source_folder/* /home/destination_folder
```

Comment: `cp -a` is preferable to `cp -r` because it preserves permissions, timestamps, symbolic links etc.  `cp -r` would reset all files to be owned by you with a creation/modification date as now, and symbolic links would be followed and their destinations duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is based on [@unfa's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/909144/1676106) and also addresses [@Marecky's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473900/how-to-use-the-dd-command-to-copy-the-content-of-a-folder/909144?newreg=0b4564d0b72c48b2b438242256573642#comment2288810_909144):

To get rid of the local path indicator (dot), you can use `find` as mentioned in [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537241):

```
SOURCE="/media/source-dir"
TARGET="/media/target-dir"
cd "$SOURCE"
find * -type d -exec mkdir -p "$TARGET/{}" \;
find * -type f -exec dd if={} of="$TARGET/{}" bs=8M oflag=direct \;
```